# Error when converting with as.numeric() in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a dataset:

```
 > x
    Treatment X1 X2
1         T1  6  7
2         T1  5  9
3         T1  8  6
4         T1  4  9
5         T1  7  9
6         T2  3  3
7         T2  1  6
8         T2  2  3
9         T3  2  3
10        T3  5  1
11        T3  3  1
12        T3  2  3
```

I am trying to find means of the columns X1 and X2. If I run the data as-is, I get an error:

```
> t1 <- subset(x[2:3], x$Treatment=="T1")
> x_vec <- colMeans(t1, na.rm = TRUE)
Error in colMeans(t1, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

So, I need to convert X1 and X2 to numeric:

```
t1$X1 <- as.numeric(as.factor(t1$X1))
t1$X2 <- as.numeric(as.factor(t1$X2))
x_vec <- colMeans(t1, na.rm = TRUE)
```

But when I do that, I get the wrong result:

```
> x_vec
 X1  X2 
6.0 4.4
```

The t1, after conversion **to as.numeric()**, shows:

```
> t1
  X1 X2
1  6  4
2  5  5
3  8  3
4  4  5
5  7  5
```

Why are the values in X2 changed after converting to numeric?

Comment: Use `as.numeric(as.character(t1$X1))`

Comment: The problem is that you are running `colMeans` on every column, and column `Treatment` is not numeric.

Comment: @neilfws - doesn't look like it - `t1` only has `x[2:3]` in it.

Comment: @thelatemail ah yes, I misread. Then I guess there are non-numeric characters in X1/X2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty common issue that newer R users hit. The issue is your use of `as.factor`. running `as.numeric` on a factor converts the value to the **numeric index** of the label, rather than converting the *label itself* to a number. Your can either remove the call to `as.factor` or run `as.character` on the factor before calling `as.numeric`.

Note that some functions like `as.data.frame` automatically convert characters to factors, which can cause problems. Check out the option `stringsAsFactors` for more info.